# WordPress wp_nav_menu with a nav tag

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm thinking about wrapping the `wp_nav_menu` with a nav tag instead of a div tag.

I've read at the WordPress codex that the container argument is only for using `ul` or `div`.

Do you guys know a way how to display the navigation in a nav tag so that the output looks like this:

```
<nav class="menu-header-menue-container">
  <ul id="menu-header-menue" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-86"><a href="home"></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close.

There is `container` argument for [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters):

> **'container'** (string) Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with.
>   Default 'div'.

Its default value is 'div', which means, that the `ul` will be wrapped with `div` tag. You can change it to `false` - `ul` won't get wrapped at all in such case.

But you can also change it to `nav` - and that is what you're looking.

Comment: oh okay cause in a other stackquestion someone was telling the guy who was asking that container is only accepting div and yeah thats why i was so confused.

Comment: @MisterLA do you have link to that question maybe?